# Windows batch programming: Indirect/nested variable evaluation

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

We have a text file that lists a bunch of paths, and a batch file that reads the lines from this file.

For instance, TargetFolders.txt might contain the line:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Acme\FooBar %VersionNumber%
```

Naturally, when we read this line from the text file (using a FOR command), the variable %%I receives the actual line text, with the % signs rather than replacing the variable values. So,

```
SET VersionNumber=7.0
FOR /F "eol=; delims=" %%I IN (TargetFolders.txt) DO (
    echo Folder: %%I
)
```

Prints

```
Folder: %ProgramFiles%\Acme\FooBar %VersionNumber%
```

How does one make it replace the actual variable values, so that it prints

```
Folder: C:\Program Files\Acme\FooBar 7.0
```

?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [How expand a CMD shell variable twice (recursively)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199931/how-expand-a-cmd-shell-variable-twice-recursively)

Comment: Hmmm it's not an exact duplicate because you have the `%...%` in place, but the link may be helpful...

Comment: lrfy: Not exactly; I'm not talking about multiple expansions, just getting it to reference the variable in the first place rather than the %name%.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SET VersionNumber=7.0
FOR /F "eol=; delims=" %%I IN (TargetFolders.txt) DO (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%J in (`echo %%I`) do echo Folder: %%J
)
```

There you go. (This is what you wanted, right?)

Comment: lrfy: Not sure I follow you. How does this solve the original issue of not being able to reference environment variables within the TXT file?  So that for instance the text file can say %ProgramFiles% and the batch file prints out C:\Program Files.

Comment: The 'echo %AAA%' part gives you the twice-evaluated string, but since it contains spaces, I guess the loop tries to iterate over the individual parts... And I can't seem to fix that.

Comment: Thanks, The backquote option is what was needed, to treat the "echo %%I" output as a command line so that the %variables% would be properly recognized.

Comment: You have an unwanted extra `=` when defining delims for %%J loop. Also, this solution will not work if a folder contains an unquoted special character. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9370376/1012053). Your use of an extra FOR with ECHO is better than my use of CALL because it doesn't mangle quoted caret `"^"`

Comment: Actually, neither is good with caret. FOR/ECHO mangles unquoted `^` whereas CALL mangles quoted `"^"`. :(

Comment: OT: I think we sort of implicitly agree here that NT shell programming is a horror in itself, compared to the linux/unix shells...

Answer (score 6):

Simply adding a CALL may solve your problem. (also your definition of VersionNumber was wrong)

```
SET VersionNumber=7.0
FOR /F "eol=; delims=" %%I IN (TargetFolders.txt) DO (
  call echo Folder: %%I
)
```

But this will fail if your file contains unquoted special characters like `&`, `>`, `<`, `|`.

For example, the following line would fail:

```
%ProgramFiles%\This&That\ %VersionNumber%
```

It will work if it is quoted

```
"%ProgramFiles%\This&That\" %VersionNumber%
```

The CALL will also mangle any quoted carets: `"^"` will become `"^^"`

The best solution would be to modify your text file and replace each `%` with `!`.

```
!ProgramFiles!\Acme\FooBar !VersionNumber!
!ProgramFiles!\This&That !VersionNumber!
```

Now you can safely use delayed expansion to expand the variables within the loop.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
SET VersionNumber=7.0
FOR /F "eol=; delims=" %%I IN (TargetFolders.txt) DO (
  echo Folder: %%I
)
```

If your text file already has `!` that you want to preserve, then it must be escaped. Also `^` will have to be escaped if it appears on a line with a `!`.

```
preserve caret ^^ and exclamation ^! by escaping
caret ^ without exclamation is no problem
```

Alternatively you can substitute variables for caret and exclamation literals

```
alternate method to preserve caret !c! and exclamation !x!
caret ^ without exclamation still no problem
```

And then define the variables in your batch

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "x=^!"
set "c=^"
SET VersionNumber=7.0
FOR /F "eol=; delims=" %%I IN (TargetFolders.txt) DO (
  echo Folder: %%I
)
```

Comment: +1 for showing the alternatives with pro/con of each.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the existing helpful answers with a **more robust variant** that also **handles the following embedded characters correctly: `& | < > ^`**<sup>[1]</sup>
:

<sup>Note that for simplicity I'm using a *string* to drive the *outer* loop, whose *literal* value - to be expanded later by the inner loop - is `%ProgramFiles%\Acme\FooBar %VersionNumber%`, due to the doubled `%` instances.</sup>

```
set "VersionNumber=0.7"
for /f "delims=" %%f in ("%%ProgramFiles%%\Acme\FooBar %%VersionNumber%%") do (
  for /f "delims=" %%g in ('echo "%%f"') do echo Folder: [%%~g]
)
```

This yields something like `Folder: [C:\Program Files\Acme\FooBar 0.7]`

Note:

- By default, `for /f` interprets a *single-quoted* string (`'...'`) as a command to execute and whose output to capture; `delims=` tells `for` to capture the output as a whole in a single variable.
  (While you *can* use `usebackq` with a `` `...` ``-enclosed command instead, there's no advantage to doing so in this case.)
- Note how the reference to the outer loop's variable is *double-quoted* (`"%%f"`), which is what allows the value to contain said special characters without breaking the `echo` command.
- Because the output will then also be double-quoted, the `~` operator is used to strip the enclosing double quotes from the captured value on echoing it (`%%~g`).

---

[1] A **solution that additionally handles embedded `"` instances** is trickier:

```
  rem Construct a variable whose value contains all shell metacharacters.
  rem % chars. meant to be treated as literals must be doubled (%%)
  rem Note the extra " at the end, which appends an unbalanced double quote. 
set "var=%%OS%% & %%ba^r | (baz) <mo'>""

  rem Embedded " chars. must be escaped as "" (doubling them).  
for /f "delims=" %%v in ('echo "%var:"=""%"') do set "expandedVar=%%~v"

  rem Note: The resulting variable's value: 
  rem  - can only be echoed *double-quoted*, as the command will otherwise break.
  rem  - still contains the *doubled* embedded double quotes, which, however,
  rem    is the escaping that other Microsoft programs expect.
echo "[%expandedVar%]"
```

This yields: `"[Windows_NT & %ba^r | (baz) <mo'>""]"`