# Batch: variable indirection: getting the value of a variable by dynamically constructed name

Tags: variables, batch-file, echo, indirection

So when I run this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set lstFolders= First Second 

set intCounter=0
for %%i in (!lstFolders!) do (
    set /a intCounter += 1
    set strFlder=%%i
    set strFolder!intCounter!=!strFlder!
    echo %%i
    echo !strFlder!
    echo !strFolder%intCounter%!
    echo !strFolder1!
    echo !strFolder2!
)

:End
pause
endlocal
```

It results with this:

```
First
First
ECHO is off.
First
ECHO is off.
Second
Second
ECHO is off.
First
Second
```

Why doesn't it allow me to echo the variable create with the format : `!strFolder%intCounter%!`? Is there another way to reference this variable and get the data that is inside of it?

Comment: While not an exact duplicate, because _this_ question also asks about _creating_ variables indirectly (and is focused on using delayed evaluation), the following question is closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9369874/45375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Caveat**: The code below only works with list values (the tokens of `%lstFolders%` such as `First`) that:

- contain neither spaces
- nor any of the following chars.: `& | < > "`

A different looping approach would be needed to handle such cases.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "lstFolders=First Second" 

set intCounter=0
for %%i in (%lstFolders%) do (
      rem Increment the counter
    set /a intCounter += 1
      rem Echo the loop variable
    echo #!intCounter!=%%i
      rem Set variable strFolder<intCounter> to the loop variable's value
    set "strFolder!intCounter!=%%i"
      rem Echo the variable created using variable indirection with for /f ('...')
    for /f "delims=" %%v in ('echo "%%strFolder!intCounter!%%"') do set "thisFolder=%%~v"
    echo %%thisFolder%% ^(via %%strFolder!intCounter!%%^)=!thisFolder!
)
```

Running the above yields:

```
#1=First
%thisFolder% (via %strFolder1%)=First
#2=Second
%thisFolder% (via %strFolder2%)=Second
```

---

What you're looking for is **variable indirection**:

- While you **can *set* a variable indirectly** (by a name that you construct dynamically from the value of *another* variable), e.g.,

  - `set "strFolder!intCounter!=%%i"`, with `!intCounter!` having a value of `1`, correctly sets variable `strFolder1` to the value of `%%i`),
- you **cannot *get*** a variable's value that way; you **need an *extra evaluation step*, which `for /f ... ('echo ...')` can provide.**:

  - `for /f "delims=" %%v in ('echo "%%strFolder!intCounter!%%"') do ...` parses the output of the command in single quotes (`echo ...`) and assigns the result as a whole (`delims=`) to variable `%%v`
    (`%%~v` removes the enclosing double quotes, which were added around the `echo` argument to make the command handle shell metacharacters such as `& | < >` correctly).
  - `%%strFolder!intCounter!%%` *immediately* evaluates `strFolder!intCounter!` to `strFolder1`, if `!intCounter!` is `1`, which, thanks to the enclosing *doubled* `%` instances, ends up as *literal* `%strFolder1%`, which is what the `echo` command sees when it is run by the `for` command, causing it to evaluate the variable reference and expand to its value.

Comment: Yes, I just put your code into a batch file and ran it, looked over it, and now i get it. Thank you so much, this is a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

As @mklement0 already said, you need an extra evaluation step.
But inspite to use `echo "%%strFolder!intCounter!%%"`, I would recommend delayed expansion.
As delayed expansion is immune to any content, `echo "%%strFolder...` will fail with content containing quotes or exclamation marks.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "lstFolders=First Second"

set intCounter=0
for %%i in (!lstFolders!) do (
    set /a intCounter+= 1
    set "strFlder=%%i"
    set "strFolder!intCounter!=!strFlder!"
    echo !strFlder!
    set "varname=strFolder!intCounter!"
    for /F "delims=" %%A in (""!varname!"") do echo Indirect %%~A=!%%~A!
)
```

The doubling of the quotes avoids problems with the eol character of the FOR/F loop.