# Eval script containing PATH in Windows CMD

Tags: windows, cmd

I need to eval the commands thrown by some command 'minishift oc-env' which has *PATH* in it.

However, it seems that it is overwriting the whole *PATH* variable.

```
C:\Users\budhram>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Users\budhram\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;.....

C:\Users\budhram>minishift oc-env
SET PATH=C:\Users\budhram\.minishift\cache\oc\v1.5.0;%PATH%;
REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM     @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minishift oc-env') DO @%i

C:\Users\budhram>SET PATH=C:\Users\budhram\.minishift\cache\oc\v1.5.0;%PATH%;

C:\Users\budhram>echo %PATH%
C:\Users\budhram\.minishift\cache\oc\v1.5.0;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Users\budhram\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;....

C:\Users\budhram>@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minishift oc-env') DO @%i

C:\Users\budhram>echo %PATH%
C:\Users\budhram\.minishift\cache\oc\v1.5.0;%PATH%;
```

Any idea how we can do that?
This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9370376/1120530 also suggest about using `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` which seems to be not working in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

```
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minishift oc-env') DO @%i
```

the `do` clause will execute

```
SET PATH=C:\Users\budhram\.minishift\cache\oc\v1.5.0;%PATH%;
```

which seems correct, BUT the problem is that after `%i` has been expanded to the indicated command, there is not a second expansion to convert `%PATH%` to the value in the variable.

You can try with

```
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minishift oc-env') DO @call %i
```

where the `call` command will force a second parse phase that will expand the `%PATH%` reference.

Comment: Awesome! Working smoothly. Thanks :)