# Batch file Variable cannot be printed in this special situation

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I want to print variable in the console.
But, I can watch %variable_name%...

This is an example code which can explain my situation.

```
Set a=%b% and i respect you, answer!
Set b=lolol i'm happy
Echo %a%
```

What I want::

```
lolol i'm happy and i respect you, answer!
```

Results::

```
%a% and i respect you, answer!
```

How can i solve this problem??
(I updated my question, sorry...)

Comment: Not a batch expert by any means, but I'd suspect the variables get expanded when seen. I.e. as written `SET a=%b%` would have to appear after `b` has been set. If batch has an indirect reference, it'd very likely have a different syntax for that, but there I am out of my depth. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369874/windows-batch-programming-indirect-nested-variable-evaluation) helps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch programming: Indirect/nested variable evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369874/windows-batch-programming-indirect-nested-variable-evaluation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need the percent signs in the content of the variable `a`. Double them to tell the parser that you want them literal instead of the (current) content of `b`.
Then you need another layer of expansion to evaluate `%a%` (variable) to `%b%` (literal with the percent signs) then to evaluate that `%b%` to the content of `b`:

```
Set a=%%b%% and i respect you, answer!
Set b=lolol i'm happy
call Echo %a%
```

Comment: Note that on the command line, as opposed to a batch script, we can't escape percent by doubling it. The best we can do is to disrupt matching the name `b` by inserting a `^` escape character, e.g. `set a=%^b%`. This would match an environment variable named `^b`, but it's unlikely for this to be defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This solution can run in this situatuon? ::set a=%%b%% is true     set b=lolol    call echo %a%

Comment: @eryksun, There is even a better way which is guaranteed to work in command line. `set "b="`. So I guess using `%^b%` is not the best we can do ;)

Comment: @sst, I don't follow you, `set "b="` clears the value of `b`. We're trying to set `a` to the literal value `%b%`. To do that we have to disrupt the first pass of the parser by having it look for a variable named `^b` instead, which we hope is not defined. Then in the second pass of the parser, the `^` escape character is removed since it's not in a quoted string, and we're left with the literal `%b%` to be assigned.

Comment: @eryksun, `to disrupt the first pass of the parser by having it look for a variable named ^b instead, which we hope is not defined` That is exactly the purpose of `set "b="`. we clear the value of `b` before using `set "a=%b%"`, so instead of betting on `^b` to be undefined, we can just make sure that `b` is undefined. Therefor there is no need to use `%^b%`, we just `%b%` with confidence. If you want to pass the command to subshell, just undefined `b` in the parent then pass `Set "a=%b%"` to subshell. (Just as an example)

Comment: @sst, if `b` is already defined you'll have to copy it to a temp variable. This gets complicated if we're using this technique to escape many variable names in an expression. I still think it's better to use `^` since in practice I've never seen environment variable names use this character. Of course this only applies to interactive use on the command line. In a batch script we can use `%%` with confidence AFAIK.

Comment: @eryksun @sst, On the command line, I use `set "Perc=%" and then set" a=%Perc%b%Perc%"`

Comment: @jeb, you've beat me to the ground :)

Comment: Thank you!! I've had this trouble for a week!