# How to interprete variable in batch string?

Tags: windows, shell, scripting, batch-file, dos

i have a problem in a string with variable included
I read a key in registry like this :

```
call:ReadReg "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" "Desktop"
echo %RegValue%

:ReadReg
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "%~1" /v "%~2" 2^>nul`) DO (
    set RegName=%%A
    set RegType=%%B
    set RegValue=%%C
)
goto:eof
```

but the value returned in RegValue is: `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`
instead of : `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Desktop`

the ECHO line display :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\alopez>echo %USERPROFILE%\Bureau
%USERPROFILE%\Bureau
```

I would like convert the registry value into a good path

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199931/how-expand-a-cmd-shell-variable-twice-recursively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `set RegValue=%%C` with `call set RegValue=%%C` This will cause variable expansion twice; once for the call command and then again for the set command.  Run this example .bat script to see it in action.

```
@echo off

set x=%%Path%%
echo %x%
echo.
call echo %x%
call set x=%x%
echo.
echo %x%
pause >nul
```