# Batch: Get the value of a variable present in the value of another variable

Tags: batch-file, variables

So, I'm making a calculator that allows its users to name their previous result in order to use them in future calculations. How it works is that when you give a name to a previous result, it creates a variable with the name chosen and its value is then set to whatever the previous result is. It looks something like this:

```
set /p equation=
::variables need to be replaced here
set /a result=%equation%
::giving a name
set /p name=
set %name%=%result%
```

The problem is, I cannot figure out a way to get the value of the variable in the equation since the equation is also a variable, so whenever I add the equation in a command with `%equation%`, it just replaces it with something like `1+%named_result%`. Is there a way I could turn the equation with the same one but where the variables are replaced with their values? (`set equation=%equation%` does not work)

Comment: Read on [delayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and using call/for to [force another expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199931/how-to-expand-a-cmd-shell-variable-twice-recursively)

Comment: That is not necessary. Any _variable name_ that appears in the equation of `SET /A` command is automatically replaced by the variable value. I.e. `set equation=1+named_result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in ('set %name% 2^>nul') do if /i "%%a"=="%name%" set "result=%%b"
```

`set %name%` lists all of the variables that start `%name%` in the format `name=value`. The `2>nul` suppresses error messages if `name` is not defined. the caret (`^`) escapes the `>` telling `cmd` that the `>` is part of the `set` command, not the `for`.

The `for /f` splits the `set` line into two parts - that before the delimiter and that after, so `name` goes to `%%a` and `value` to `%%b`. Now `set` will output any name that *starts* with *name* so it will match `name`, `named` `names` etc. consequently, we need to choose the output line where the name exactly matches (hence the `if`) and to make the match case-insensitive (the `/i` on the `if` command.

And if the test is passed, assign the value to your chosen variable.

Comment: I put Batch away in favor of C# now. But thanks anyway. I'm sure it will be useful to someone at some point. :)