# Importing text, (including a variable), from a text file

Tags: batch-file

I tried this code to import the full path from a text file:

```bash
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr /I "makedir=" config.txt') do md "%%a"
```

The full path in txt file is:

```
makdir=%appdata%/test
```

My problem is the path returns as text, not as a directory path. Essentially I need `%appdata%` to expand as opposed to remain in its variable form.

Comment: Hi G Zone ... welcome to stackoverflow!  pls provide all of the relevant code.

Comment: @Beel, all the required code is there! THE OP has shown that the content of `%%a` will be the literal string `%appdata%/test`, _(i.e. the 2nd token of `makdir=%appdata%/test` when delimited by the `=` character)_. My assumption, as I edited the question, was that they wanted the expanded variable value string, not the variable. For example: `C:\Users\GZone\AppData\Roaming/test`, not `%appdata/test%`. It should be noted however that the code searches for a line containing the substring `makedir`, but the file itself shows a string `makdir=`.

Comment: @Compo ... so expectation is that `makdir=...` is the content of `config.txt`?  and we realize that that text contains, `makdir` and not `makedir`, right?

Comment: My comment also mentions that, @Beel, but that would be irrelevant to your comment, as they've still shown "all of the relevant code", regardless of a probable typo. _At worst they've simply not provided a more complete representation of the possible entries in the text file `config.txt`._ Personally I would advise that they replace `tokens=2` with `tokens=1,*`, then replace the `%%a` in the `do` with `%%b`.

Comment: Suggest reviewing this answer ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199931/how-to-expand-a-cmd-shell-variable-twice-recursively

Comment: i try this but i cant get full path for /F "tokens=1,* delims=rr=" %%b in ('findstr /I "rr=" config.txt') do md %%b

Comment: `delims=rr=` delimits the string at each `r`, each `r`, and each `=`. Delimiters are one-char only (several chars are possible, but it splits at each occurrence of one or more of those).

Comment: Change `makdir=%appdata%/test` in the file by `makdir=!appdata!/test` and `EnableDelayedExpansion` in your code. That is it...

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q76507677.txt"

FOR /f "tokens=2delims==" %%e IN ('findstr /I "makedir=" "%filename1%"') DO (
 CALL md "%%e"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Note that in the Windows world, `\` is a directory-separator and `/` is a switch-indicator. Windows often, but not always, makes the translation. Best to use the correct form.

For instance, `md` creates the directory quite happily with `/` but `dir` will object.